# How to make a text spinner in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, spinner, preg-match-all

I am trying to create a parser for this kind of texts:

```
{{texta1|texta2|texta3} {texta11|texta22}|{textb1|textb2} {textb11|textb22}}
```

I managed to get this regex `~(?<={).*?(?=})~U` working to match the main content inside the first { and last }, but when I want to split {a|b|c}|{aa|bb|cc} with explode I am having problems since it wont split each {} into a separated array but will split every |, and if I split it using }|{, the output then gets kinda broken to try to parse it for later spinning cause a } and { will be missing on the output.

Does someone has a method to do this with regex or something like that that doesn't require tons of code?

Comment: What is your desired output for this? I don't entirely understand.

Comment: Text spinners are commonly used by blackhat SEOs (though many popular self-proclaimed whitehat SEO communities also endorse their use) to create large volumes of low quality content in a very short amount of time. It's used to create "unique" content for spam sites (link wheels, link farms, etc.), though ultimately it's just hundreds of copies of the same content with different combinations of synonyms substituted in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regex is not made for building parsers. there are a million posts on this site showing why. something like this is maybe more suited http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php